# Stratified SRS vs. probability-proportional-to-size (PPS) sampling - what's the difference?

Tags: probability, sampling, survey, stratification, weighted-sampling

If my understanding is correct, the key difference is that:

1. In stratified SRS you intentionally draw $N_h$ samples from each of your $k$ strata ($h = 1...k$, $\sum_{1}^{k}{N_h} = N$) and are therefore guaranteed to get a certain number, $N_h$, from each stratum by design.
2. In PPS you are modifying the probability of selection for each unit to be proportional to the size of the stratum containing that unit, $p_h = \frac{x_h}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i}}$ (where $x$ is the number of units in a stratum), but you aren't guaranteed to hit a certain number of samples per unit.

Is this correct?

What I *don't* understand is why you would use one of these over the other. I haven't been able to find any comparison between the two online, can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: In PPS, strata aren't (necessarily) involved. Instead, each unit's prob is proportional to the "size" of the **unit** itself. For example, you might sample companies proportionally to the number of employees at the company, or its gross income, or something. In this example the units are the companies, not employees or dollars. Each unit (company) has **its own** sampling prob, unlike in stratified sampling.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing financial audits, there is some research that Stratified SRS does a better job hitting the nominal confidence levels you're shooting for:

http://www.asasrms.org/Proceedings/y2002/Files/JSM2002-000704.pdf

In general, SRS gives you an equal chance of hitting all transactions, low and high, which is a nice property if you think there is risk spread evenly across the population.

PPS can be a good way to make sure you get "coverage" of high dollar items, which is not a statistical consideration necessarily, but is sometimes a leadership consideration. The issue of non-equal chance of selection, especially low chances for small dollar items, could be an issue since large dollar items often received better oversight than smaller transactions, so you might be unintentionally excluding low-dollar, high-risk items.